# R - more or equal (≥)-sign shows/saves as equal sign (=)

Tags: r, unicode

When I create graphs with R from our databas the signs "≥" and "≤" are diplayed/saved as "=". 
I can't even paste in "≥" in R:s command line. An other exampel from R studio are print("≥") 
[1] "="

All other symbols/characters that we use are displayd correctly. We use R for automatic report generation so I can't replace with unicode ("\u2265") and "\u2264").
Is there an reason why R can't handle this correctly? Our workaround is to use ">=" but i rather have the more compact form.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252    LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252
```

Comment: You should put together a small example of the code you are using and post that.  It's hard to say what's going wrong if we don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: I cant even paste in "≥" in R:s command line. An other exampel from R studio are:print("≥")
[1] "="

Comment: That looks like a Windows-specific bug, because the `"≥"` character is not available in your local encoding, code page 1252.  I use a Mac which works in UTF-8, and things are fine there.  When I run your example in Windows I see the same as you, but `print("\u2265")` works fine for me in both systems.

Comment: Thank you for the information! It does not solve my problem but it explains why.